# How to set a buy order in binance api

Tags: javascript, binance, binance-api-client

I am trying to set a buy order with binance api in Javascript/Nodejs.
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-api-node
For example, assume that last price of X coin is 4.25 
I want to buy when its price increased to 4.32 
When i use order api;

```
await client.order({
   symbol: X,
   side: 'BUY',
   type: 'LIMIT',
   quantity: quantity,
   price: 4.32
})
```

It always buy at 4.25. Because last price of X coin is 4.25 but i want to set an order which buy at 4.32. How can i achieve that ?
I also tried orderOco api;

```
await client.orderOco({
   symbol: X,
   side: 'BUY',
   quantity: quantity,
   price: 4.32, 
   stopPrice: 4.13,
   stopLimitPrice: 4.05,
});
```

As a result, i get an error: "The relationship of the prices for the orders is not correct."
Binance API Document says following order but i couldnt understand.
Price Restrictions:
SELL: Limit Price > Last Price > Stop Price
BUY: Limit Price < Last Price < Stop Price

Which order should used among price, stopPrice and stopLimitPrice ?

Comment: is there any solution for this issue?